# How to set more margins

Tags: matplotlib

I have a pyplot code. 
Since I want to group multiple bars, I am trying to write text in the graph using plt.annotate.
However, as you can see in the picture, the word 'Something' in left bottom gets cropped. Does anyone know How I can fix this? 
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import operator as o
import numpy as np

n_groups = 5
means_men = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
std_men = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

means_women = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
std_women = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35

opacity = 0.4
error_config = {'ecolor': '0.3'}
rects1 = plt.bar(index, means_men, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='b', yerr=std_men, error_kw=error_config, label='Men')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, means_women, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='r',
                 yerr=std_women,
                 error_kw=error_config,
                 label='Women')

#plt.xlabel('Group')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.annotate('Something', (0,0), (50,-40), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', va='top');
plt.annotate('Something', (0,0), (200,-20), xycoords = 'axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', va='top');
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))
plt.legend()

plt.savefig('barchart_3.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, matplotlib sometimes clips too aggressively. If you add `bbox_inches='tight'` to save fig this should include the figure correctly,

```
plt.savefig('barchart_3.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

More generally, you can adjust your main figure with something like,

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped! :)